# PHP-7: mysqli query #2 returns no results unless query #1 is closed - why?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have some PHP-7 code (using "mysqli"), that, of course, wants to execute several queries and to scroll through their result sets.  However, I am finding that *unless* I **close()** the previous statement, the next statement ... although it seems to run ... produces no results.

(That is to say, the affected-rows count will return zero.)

I am at a loss to explain this behavior . . .

(Incidentally, the necessary function seemed to be *statement-* closing.  Not disposing of result sets.)

= = =

I do *not* believe that this is a duplicate of the question cited, because that answer is clearly using **mysqli_multi_query** and I am not.  I am performing three different, unrelated queries, in three consecutive loops.

If you are suggesting that I am "accumulating multiple result-sets" and just don't know it, but I do not believe that this is my use-case.  The only references to those API-calls that I have seen, specifically make use of the multi-query call, which I am *not* using.  But I would be **delighted** to learn that I am wrong here.

Code example

```
echo "Test: simple query.\n"; 
$iter = DB::query('select count(*) from address_book'); 
echo "Query returned " . $iter->rowCount() . " results.\n"; 

foreach ($iter as $v) 
    print_r($v); 

$iter = null;  // WITHOUT this, next stmt will produce no results.

echo "Test: simple query again.\n"; 
$iter = DB::query('select count(*) from address_book'); 
echo "Query returned " . $iter->rowCount() . " results.\n"; 

foreach ($iter as $v) 
    print_r($v); 

 $iter = null;  // DITTO ...
```

And here are the iterator-support functions:

```
// Retrieve current element
public function current () {
    if ($this->current == null) {
        $this->current = $this->fetch();
    }

    return $this->current;
}

// Retrieve value of next element
public function next () {
    $this->current = $this->fetch();
    $this->position++;

    return $this->current;
}


// Retrieve key of current element
public function key () {
    return $this->position;
}


// Check if current position is valid - used to stop an iterator
public function valid () {
    if ($this->position >= 0 && $this->position < $this->rowCount()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

// Rewind the iterator to the first element
public function rewind () {
    $this->checkNoResultException();
    $this->position = 0;
    $this->_result->data_seek(0);
}
```

And here is 'query':

```
public static function query ( $stmt, $params = null ) {
    $objInstance = self::getInstance();

    try {
        if ($params === null) {
            return $objInstance->query($stmt);
        }
        else {
            return $objInstance->prepare($stmt)->execute($params);
        }
    }
    catch(MysqliException $e) {
        error_log("(DB::query) Query failed: " . $e->getMessage());
        die("SQL Query failed -- see log");
    }
}
```

Comment: See the DUP answers, but not the Accepted answer as that is wrong, assuming you are doing a `multi_query()`

Comment: I don't think that I double-posted anything (oops), so if this is "an exact duplicate," please point to what it is a duplicate OF!  :-)  I'd be a very happy boy, indeed, if the answer's right under my nose and I didn't see it.

Comment: Edited post to indicate that I do __not__ think that this is a dupe.  The cited article uses the "multi-query" API, and I do not.

Comment: As a quick confirmation, I added code to call "more_results()" after an iterator ended, and there were **no more** results, as I expected.  Therefore, the "duplicate" question *does not* apply here.

Comment: Well in that case, SHOW THE CODE or at least a simple example, so any confusion about the code you are using will __instantly dissapear__ Otherwise this will be a candidate for closing for a number of other reasons

Comment: Is this a simple case of RE-USING the same variable i.e. `$result` in more than one query in a loop, therefore mashing the contents of `$result` with a new query?

Comment: (Well, that's the code that I have.)  A simple singleton returning a statement object that does a fetch on the cursor within the iterator methods.  The statements "$iter = null;" are added to explicitly invoke the destructor, which explicitly closes statement and result handles.  Basically, I have created two mysqli::statement objects within this code, one after the other, and the second is returning "no results" unless the first has been closed!

Comment: please post extra info as an edit to your question. Nobody can read code in comments

Comment: No, although I thought of that.  The 'query()' method always returns a new object which self-contains both its statement handle and its result-set.  When the object returned by 'query()' is destroyed, both are destroyed, and there aren't any opps for "mashing." === Thanks for editing the question to add that!  :-)  You beat me to it.

Comment: As what `DB::query()` does is rather relevant, would you post that as well please

Comment: By your command, Centurion ...  ;-)  "DB.query" has been added.

Comment: Yup there we go. The `$iter = null;`  will cause the API to be left in a state where it thinks there is still a result set that need processed. **Basically because there is** If you want to stop in the middle of a logical sequence you will have to close that result before attempting to get the API to start another

Comment: Oh and Garbage collection does not happen just because you set something to NULL. It just sets that bit of memory available for garbage collection

Comment: Actually, `$iter = null;` is what *fixed* it.  __Without__ this statement, it fails. ##  The "select count()" seems to be an artifact of my pasting.  Obviously the actual statement contains a star.

Comment: Well in that case its the equivalent of closing but without the benefit of doing it correctly

Comment: Yes, I agree.  This isn't enough to trigger garbage collection, and yet it does cause the code to work, as does adding an explicit statement `close()` call to the iterator's `valid()` call when it returns false to end the loop.  The strange thing is, the presence or absence of that one fairly-nonsensical "set-to-null" statement has a 100%-reproducible effect.  (P.S. Can you add an "answer" so I can send an up-vote your way?  I am very grateful for your prompt reply and dogged persistence.)

Comment: Not necessary, I would have no idea how to word it

Comment: Well, I'm zeroing in on your comment:  "Basically because there is. If you want to stop in the middle of a logical sequence you will have to close that result before attempting to get the API to start another."  ... *"You will have to close that result before attempting to get the API ... to start ... another ..."*  Hmmm.  Looking once again amongst the so-so official docs to find one really good page.  I'm using buffered result sets, read the first one all the way, and, gosh, what if I wanted to loop through multiple result-sets in nested loops?  (This app DOES that!) (Heh, don't ask...)

Comment: Enjoy and Good luck,

Comment: Thanks again.  I posted an "answer" to summarize what I've found so far, and the third bullet-point, about using *different* variable-names, is quite-easily the most screwball.  If you use different variable-names, *or* if you close() the first before using it a second time, it works.  Yeah, you heard me right ... different variable-names.  Yeah, I *know* it doesn't make a lick of sense!  ... O_o ... Almost like there's some kind of funky race-condition going on in the API.

Answer (score 0):

*For closure:*   I wound up “resolving” this problem ... sort of ... by changing the class to do a `fetch_all()` on the cursor, storing the entire result-set in an array, then immediately closing the handle itself.   Since I know that I am always dealing with reasonably-sized result sets on a capacious machine, this actually allowed me to effectively circumvent several ... “weirdnesses.”

I never did arrive at a satisfactory explanation as to why the observed behavior was occurring in the first place . . .

Comment: the explanation is embarrasingly simple but I want to ask first, what is that MysqliException you are trying to catch in your class? Did you ever managed to catch one?

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to "answer" this question, not because it's really-answered but to ... first of all, give a "shout-out" to RiggsFolly for immediately jumping in to help with the 18-comment exchange which follows above.  I am *very, very* appreciative of his quickness and persistence.

---

The question is not completely resolved yet, but I have found a number of interesting things in the test-case code shown above:

• If you set `$iter = null;` as shown above, the problem reliably disappears ... even though setting a variable to `null` does **not** obligate PHP to perform garbage-collection immediately. *(However, I do see the destructor being called immediately!)*

• If you call `$iter->close()`, which in my code will close both the result-handle and the statement-handle, the problem disappears.

• Also *(!)* if you use a *different* variable to perform the second query, the problem *also* disappears!  (In other words, change `$iter` to, say, `$iter1` and `$iter2`.

^^^ **This last bullet-point is MOST interesting, and unexpected!** ^^^

As a precaution, I have also added an explicit `__destruct` method on the statement-object to explicitly call its `close()` method, explicitly destroying both statement and result handles, if they exist, as soon as cleanup does happen.  This does not affect the outcome, but it makes me feel a little warm-and-fuzzier, I guess . . .

I welcome any further insights on this issue, because it sure confuses the heck outa me.  :-D

Comment: Although these kind of details are useful and pertinent your the question, *this is not an answer*.  You should add these details to your question and remove this.